# Apply Conditional Formatting to Cell on Left

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet with 15,000 rows and 30 columns, and have applied a conditional formatting to column X to color it when it contains a certain text. This works as expected; however, I want to apply this same formatting to the cell immediately to the left (column W) as well. Is this possible?

Based upon what you say below, this is what I tried:
[image]

The formatting is not working. Is the lookup formula not correct?

Note: Since I never know how many rows I may have at any time, I am trying to apply the formatting to the entire column instead of a specified range of cells.

EDIT:

The $X1 trick works!
[image]

You are the BEST! Many thanks to all of you!

Comment: Just change all of the cell references in your formula to use an absolute column e.g. `$A1` in place of `A1` and change the **Applies to** to include column W.

Comment: Try to change the fórmula to `$X1` instead of `$X:$X`. You want to check the "V" flag of each individual cell, not the entire column, right? By locking only the Column part of the range, the row will automatically adjust itself for each row, so in row 1 it will check for data in X1, in row 2 will check the data for row X2 and so forth. If you leave as `$X:$X`, in each row it will try to check the data for the entire range (but I might be wrong here)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :)

Comment: Yes, I was checking for each cell, and I didn't know about the unlocked part (row) automatically changing. Now that you explained it that way, it makes sense to me. This was a real learning exercise for me!

Comment: Also, just FYI - applying a conditional format to an entire column(s) (`$W:$X`) can cause your file to be much larger, or take more time calculating things, as that's a huge range. If you can, I suggest limiting it to your table, or at the very least, just not use a whole column. Of course, if it works and the processing time isn't too bad, then I'd leave it. Just thought to note.

Comment: I have not noticed any performance issue with doing the entire column like this. In fact, every week I wipe out the data and copy it from a CSV generated by PostgreSQL, and the formatting changes pretty much instantaneously as soon as the new data is pasted in. But I will keep that in mind though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course!

Your conditional format range will look something like this:

[image]

Just change the (highlighted) range to `$E$1:$F7` to apply the formatting to both columns.  This doesn't affect your condition at all.

[image]

As Jeeped points out, any time you change the "Applies To", you should double check the Formula and make sure it didn't change. Using anchors (`$`) in your range helps greatly with this. Note how in my formula, I have `=Left($F1,3)...` The `F` is anchored.  I'm pretty sure if that was just `Left(F1,3)`, and I adjust the "Applies To" range to `$E$1:$F$7`, the *formula* would "update" itself to be `=Left(E1,3)...` which isn't what I wanted.

Comment: As per my comment to the original question, the column references should be locked as in your images (but unstated in the narrative). Sometimes you need to check the formula after the change to the **Applies to** to ensure that nothing changed.

Comment: @Jeeped - Excellent comment. It took me way too long to finally learn/pay attention to the anchoring. I just wanted to show simply how to change columns. But yes, OP may need to adjust the formula or "Applies To" depending on how he has it set up.